# Cycles: Material full transparency, but still seeing parts of object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to fade out an object by using a transparency BSDF. With Transparency set to 0 it looks like:

[image: Transparency set to 0]

When turning the transparency up to 100% to get the structure opaque I get this result:

[image: Transparency set to 100]

I have no idea where those dark areas are coming from. The mesh I'm using has been imported from an obj file and was originaly created with a CAD software. I have tried to recalculate surfaces and removed all doubles, but I'm still getting those dark areas.

As I want to use it in an animation I think I could turn up transparency and just before it should go 100% transparent I'd set a keyframe on Restrict Rendering in Object Explorer, but I think it still might look a bit "harsh".

Does anyone has an idea, what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Under your Material Panel >> Settings >> Surface... Is your Transparent Shadows option checked?

Comment: Yes it is checked. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: There is a mix shader with an unconected socket, could that be causing so sort of trouble, vene though the next mix node is ignoring it?

Comment: Gandalf3 is right. His question "Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?", is about the same problem. Thanks for the help and sorry for the duplicate.